# array index out of bounds exception , is this meant to happen?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

im attempting to test a program in java and i am getting an array index out of bounds exception that i dont believe should be thrown. have a look at this code and tell me if im missing something? eclipse is telling me the error is being thrown in the location where i have added a comment to show it

```
class maze{

private int cols; // number of columns in maze  
private int rows; // number of rows in maze
private String name;
private weightedGraph<Integer> graph;
private dijkstra solution;
public char[][] mazeStore;

public maze(String filename){

    try{

        FileReader r = new FileReader(filename);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(r);
        this.rows = s.nextInt();
        this.cols = s.nextInt();
        this.name = filename;


        this.mazeStore = new char[(2*rows)+1][(2*cols)+1];
        String line = s.nextLine();
        for(int k = 0; k < ((2*rows)+1); k++){

            char[] temp = line.toCharArray();

            for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
                mazeStore[k][i] = temp[i];
                line = s.nextLine();
            }
        }



        graph = new weightedGraph<Integer>(rows*cols); 


        for(int y = 1; y < 2*rows; y++){
            for(int x = 1; x < 2*cols; x++){
                if((x % 2 == 1) && (y % 2 == 0)){
                    if(mazeStore[x][y] != '-'){ // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS THROWN 
                        int label = (x - 1) + (x / 2);
                        graph.addEdge(label, label+cols, 1);
                        graph.addEdge(label+cols, label, 1);
                    }
                }

                if((x % 2 == 0) && (y % 2 == 1)){
                    if(mazeStore[x][y] != '|'){
                        int label = ((x - 1) + (x / 2)) + (y / 2);
                        graph.addEdge(label, label+1, 1);
                        graph.addEdge(label+1, label, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }



        this.solution = new dijkstra(graph, 0); 


    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.err.println("FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Well, what are the values of `x` and `y` at that point, and what are the lengths of the arrays involved?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Copy/paste the error messages.

Comment: i think x should be where y is and vice versa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You initialized array

```
new char[(2*rows)+1][(2*cols)+1]
```

but iterating it

```
for(int y = 1; y < 2*rows; y++){//y row iterator
    for(int x = 1; x < 2*cols; x++){//x col iterator
```

so it should be 
`mazeStore[y][x]` not `mazeStore[x][y]`

Comment: @Liam Yes, exactly.  Incidentally, this is why variables like "x" and "y" are to be avoided in most places.   Think how much clearer it would have been had this instead been written as `for (int row=1; row < (2*rows); row++)`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

you have youre varaibles out of order.  youre outter most loop is based on rows but youre using it in the array you initialized to be the size of columns